# Alert user with selection from bootstrap button

Tags: jquery

Following this JSFiddle, I'm trying to alert() the user of his selection after he selects a button from the 'likert scale'.

https://jsfiddle.net/taxvkvu9/

Trying something like:

```
$(".btn btn-default").click(function () {
alert(event.relatedTarget.textContent);
})
```

however it does not seem to be working. What am I missing?

Comment: you have a typo going on and you didn't pass event as a param to the callback function

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a period and remove the space

```
$(".btn.btn-default").click(function () {
  alert($(this).text()); /* this alerts the text content of the button */
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `.` in `$(".btn btn-default")`, Write Like this `$(".btn.btn-default")`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taxvkvu9/1/)

Comment: Actually i missed something see my Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/taxvkvu9/1/ @X'Byte

Comment: Am trying something like             alert(event.relatedTarget.textContent);
 but it still doesn't work. 'Hello' alert works.

Comment: what is textContent ? you need to define it

Comment: Right. So what can I do to alert back the user's choice? ie. 1,2, etc ?

Comment: you want to show which button user have selected right ?

Comment: so you need to use Jquery .text() see here https://jsfiddle.net/taxvkvu9/2/

Comment: Darren Sweeney answered before - upvoted yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn .btn-default").on("click",function() {
    alert(event.relatedTarget.textContent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this below code..

```
$(".btn-toolbar button").click(function () {
  alert($(this).html());
});
```